# How to use pick list in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

**Component**

```
 <aura:component controller="contactSaveCtrl" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="selectedLookUpRecord" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="onPicklistChange" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="id" />
    <aura:attribute name="objContact" type="AccountContactRole__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'AccountContactRole__c',
                                                                            'Contact_c': '',
                                                                            'Role__c': '',
                                                                            'ActiveStatus__c': '',
                                                                            'Start_Date__c': '',
                                                                            'End_Date__c': '', 
                                                                            'Primary__c': ''
                                                                            }"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <div class="slds-form-element">
      <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select Label</label>
      <div class="slds-select_container">
         <ui:inputSelect  aura:id="role" class="slds-select"  change="{!c.onPicklistChange}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-m-around_large">

    <c:customLookup aura:id="contactlookup" objectAPIName="Contact" IconName="standard:Contact" label="contact" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}"/>
        <br/>
        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkBoxall" value="{!v.objContact.ActiveStatus__c}" label="Active Status"/>
        <br/>  
        <ui:inputDate aura:id="StartDateField" value="{!v.objContact.Start_Date__c}" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy" label="Start Date"/>
        <ui:inputDate aura:id="EndDateField" value="{!v.objContact.End_Date__c}" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy" label="Inactive End Date"/>

        <br/>
        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkBox" value="{!v.objContact.Primary__c}" label="Primary"/>    
        <br/>  
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveContactRecord}"/>             
            <lightning:button name="cancel" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}"/>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
saveContactRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    //getting the Accountcontactrole information
        var conObj = component.get("v.objContact"); 

   // console.log('contact : ' + JSON.stringify(component.get('v.selectedLookUpRecord')));


    conObj.Account__c      = component.get('v.recordId');  
    conObj.Contact__c      = component.get('v.selectedLookUpRecord').Id;
    conObj.Role__c         = component.find('conrole').get('v.value');
    conObj.ActiveStatus__c = component.find('checkBoxall').get('v.value');
    conObj.Start_Date__c   = component.find('StartDateField').get('v.value');
    conObj.End_Date__c     = component.find('EndDateField').get('v.value');
    conObj.Primary__c      = component.find('checkBox').get('v.value');

    component.set("v.objContact",conObj);         

    //Calling the Apex Function
    var action = component.get('c.saveContact');
     //Setting the Apex Parameter
    action.setParams({
        "objContact": component.get("v.objContact")

    });
    //Setting the Callback
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    //get the response state
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state == "SUCCESS") {
        //Reset Form
         var newCandidate = {'sobjectType': 'AccountContactRole__c',
                                'Contact_c': '',
                                'Role__c': '',
                                'ActiveStatus__c': '',
                                'Start_Date__c': '',
                                'End_Date__c': '', 
                                'Primary__c': ''
                               };
          //resetting the Values in the form
         component.set("v.objContact",newCandidate);
            alert('Record is Created Successfully');
      } else if(state == "ERROR"){
            alert('Error in calling server side action');
        }
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);

},
 handleCancel : function(component) {

    //closes the modal or popover from the component

    component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();

},
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchPickListVal(component, 'Industry', 'role');
},
onPicklistChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    // get the value of select option
    alert(event.getSource().get("v.value"));
}
})
```

**Apex class**

```
public with sharing class contactSaveCtrl {
 @AuraEnabled 
public static void saveContact(AccountContactRole__c objContact){

    try{
        System.debug('accountcontactrecord::createRecord::candidate'+objContact);

        if(objContact != null){


            insert objContact;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex){
         system.debug('error : ' + ex.getMessage() + '--' + ex.getLineNumber());
        throw ex;
    }

    system.debug('check data :'+objContact.id);
}
```

[image]

I am not able to get the Picklist field(Role__c). Can anyone please suggest me how to get picklist field with all values.

Comment: Use force:inputfield or lightning:inputfield to get the lookup like apex:inputfield please check their limitation before you start. Any reason you used customization for lookup?

Comment: Your question title seems to mention a look up field, whereas in the details, you are referring to a picklist field. What is your exact issue here?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't leveraging lightning:recordForm?

Comment: Hi, Jayant sorry I asked for picklist field only. I changed my question.

Comment: Hi Avijit I used lightning:inputfield only but didn't work. We have a button in ralted list of custom object under account. if we click on that button we are saving custom object record under accout using VF Page. Now this VF Page and button we need to use in lightning. The VF Page is having total 7 fiedls including lookup field and picklist field. I have used re usable component for lookup but I am not sure how to get Pick list field.

Comment: <force:inputField value="{!v.obj.Role__c}"/> use this . Should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code you should try. 
// In component

```
<aura:attribute name="objContact" type="AccountContactRole__c"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.objContact.Role__c}" action="{!c.myfun}"/>
<force:inputField value="{!v.objContact.Role__c}" aura:id="myRole"/>
```

in Js [Make sure you take care of case, JS is case sensitive]

```
{(
  myfun:function(cmp,event,helper){
     // To read the value
     var objContact = cpm.get("v.objContact");
     console.log("******* Role is ********" + objContact.Role__c);
     // To set the value 
     cmp.set("v.objContact.Role__c" ,"== Your ==Val" );
  },
)}
```

To add label with lookup as well as the required you can use below there is no label attribute associated with force:inputField.

```
 <div class="slds-form-element slds-hidden" id="body-div-taskform-assignto" aura:id="yourlookup">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" id="body-div-taskform-assignto-label"><abbr title="required" class="slds-required" lightning-grouped-combobox_grouped-combobox="">*</abbr>Lookup Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control" id="body-div-taskform-assignto-control">
        <force:inputField value="{!v.objContact.Role__c}" class="field " aura:id="yourlookupField"  required="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But we don't have a label for this field right.